# Cannot create package with opencv2 dependency using ROS Groovy

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, opencv2, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am starting the [Image_Transport tutorials](http://ros.org/wiki/image_transport/Tutorials) and when I try to create a package with the stated dependencies I am getting the following error:

```
pedro@ubuntu:~/catkin_ws/src$ roscreate-pkg learning_image_transport image_transport opencv2 cv_bridge
ERROR: dependency [opencv2] cannot be found
```

How can I correct this error? I am using ROS Groovy running in Ubuntu 12.10. Any help is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65755/cannot-create-package-with-opencv2-dependency-using-ros-groovy/) by [Pedro_85](https://answers.ros.org/users/4925/pedro_85/) on ROS Answers with karma: 182 on 2013-06-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are trying to create a package that depends on **opencv2** and it seems that you don't have **opencv2** installed yet.

However, I would suggest you to create a catkin package, as you are using **Groovy** and you are inside a **catkin** workspace. This tutorial seems to have been last edited before **Groovy** was released, and that is why it is not creating a **catkin** package.

To make sure you have **opencv2** installed, try:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-opencv2
```

Retry creating your package after that.
You can either follow the tutorial or create a catking package:

```
$ catkin_create_pkg learning_image_transport image_transport opencv2 cv_bridge
```

---

Originally posted by [Joao Ferreira](https://answers.ros.org/users/13366/joao-ferreira/) with karma: 81 on 2014-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K. Zeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/18898/k.-zeng/) on 2014-10-07**:
How do I install opencv2 when I have ROS Indigo? The ROS wiki says that "Since Indigo, OpenCV is not released from ROS infrastructure. Its ROS-interface package vision_opencv depends on standalone libopencv* packages".